# Opening a URL from the terminal in different spaces macOS

Tags: macos, browser, shell-script, automation

If I run `open https://example.com` from the terminal and then switch to another space with a safari window open and run the same command, the safari window in my current space will just get focused and the URL itself will not open.

How can I force the `open` command to switch me to the other space if that is where the URL is open or just always open it in the current space?

Answer (score 1):

`python -mwebbrowser http://example.com`

Did some googling and that does what I want. It switches me to the other space since thats where the URL is open. I wish there was a way to just force opening in my current space always.

Comment: My real account is this whoops.